# Get application root URL within .js file

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to get my applications root URL from within a .js file.  A solution I came upon suggested to use:

`window.location.origin`

However, because the site is hosted in a virtual directory in IIS, that only returns `http://www.whatever.com`, but I need it to return `http://www.whatever.com/mydir`.  This might seem like simple string parsing, but I debug using localhost where there is no virtual dir, so I need a solution that is available from with a .js file (not a script block within an HTML document) and is dynamic in that it will work with and without a virtual directory.

Comment: Impossible. How should the client know about the server's internal directory structure? If, however, the url of that page contains the path, have a look at top.location.href

Comment: Would this work for you (assuming you only want the first directory): `window.location.origin + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]`

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this from client side code.

The browser only knows about URLs. It has no way to know how you used them to organise your site.

If you want to tell the browser the `/mydir` is special, then you'll need to encode that in the data you send to it (e.g. in a `<meta>` element).